# Suppose A is $n$ x $n$ and the equation A $\vec{x} = \vec{b}$ has a solution for each $\vec{b}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: matrices, inverse

Explain why A must be invertible. Can someone explain why? I am a little confused here.

Comment: The downvotes are probably because you haven't explained your thoughts about the problem.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it has a solution for each b, (the linear map associated to) $A$ is surjective. But in finite dimensions, for linear maps, the injectivity is equivalent to the surjectivity (it's a consequence of the rank-nullity theorem). Hence the bijectivity, or, in other words, the invertibility of the matrix A

Answer (score 0):

Hint: consider the system $AX=I$. Apply the hypothesis to the columns of $A$.